# How to keep stroke size unchanged when changing brush in Affinity Designer?

Tags: affinity-designer

Every time I switch brush type in Affinity Designer, the stroke size changes as well. How do I prevent this behaviour, keeping the same brush size when changing the brush type?.

[image: Changing brush type, but stroke size changes as well]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double-click a brush in the Brushes palette. You get an editing dialog for brush properties. One of them is the default width.

Making a brushset with proper defaul widths is your only option, there's not available such option as "use previous brush width" or "set the brush width for the painting tool". Unfortunate, but true.

Comment: I found the option you are referring to, but I was hoping for a better alternative. It's a shame that is the only way though. I suppose I could ask for a feature request to the Affinity team. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Hold down the Option key (Mac) or ALT (PC) when choosing a different brush. Size will remain unchanged (Affinity 1.7). This might be new since this question was posted.